# Since yt-dlp simulates a browser, can it be fingerprinted in the same ways (e.g. canvas and audiocontext)?

Tags: web-browser, fingerprinting

I know that wget and curl can mitigate fingerprinting (aside from http header and user agent), but will [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) give away more data?

Answer (score 1):

yt-dlp does not *"simulate a browser"* and neither do wget or curl. It has no capabilities to universally execute Javascript like the browser, has no canvas and no audiocontext and thus no fingerprinting at this level can be used. But, it still shows characteristic behavior (like only rudimentary supporting Javascript) which can be used to distinguish it from real browsers.